# What's the correct way to detect view hierarchy for backButton purposes?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

This question applies to an update I'm making to [`MBPlacePickerController`](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBPlacePickerController).

I'm building a custom view controller that will sometimes be displayed modally in its own `UINavigationController` and other times pushed onto an existing navigation controller stack.

If my view controller is presented modally, I want to display my own "Done" button instead of the back button, on the right, and a second button on the left.

If the view controller is being displayed on the navigation stack, I want to display the default back button, and then I want to display the other button on the right.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to detect the view controller hierarchy, but perhaps the "right" way to do this is check for the back button of the previous view controller itself, and then set the navigationItem appropriately.

Can anyone shed some light?

Edit:

For clarity, I'm working on an update to my [`MBPlacePickerController`](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBPlacePickerController) library which is on GitHub. I use a navigation controller to display the "automatic" and "done" buttons, so I always want a navigation controller. The only question is if the place picker controller is providing the navigation controller (in which case that will be shown modally) or if the place picker is being pushed onto another navigation controller.

The question is how to present the back button. Am I using a done button, or using the built in back button? I'm trying to work out the best way to detect this.

Essentially, if I try to push the place picker onto an existing navigation controller hierarchy, I don't want the done button to show. If I present in  a new view controller, I need to show my own done button.

Also, I'll need to detect the correct way to dismiss my view controller if I have the done button. (That's simpler, because I can assume that if the done button is there, we're not using the back button, and I can dismiss the modally presented navigation controller.)

Comment: Could you just bring on your custom view controller modally (not being in a navigation controller stack) then have your "Done" button simply dismiss the current view controller? You will then be returned to the previous view controller (and navigation controller stack) that you came from.

Comment: Is what you are asking how to determine if your ViewController was pushed or shown modally!? I am kind of confused by the "be displayed modally in its own UINavigationController" part, is that already working or something you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you (the view controller in question) are in a navigation hierarchy, you have a non-nil `navigationController`. If you're being presented modally, you have a non-nil `presentingViewController`. Thus, you know which you are in, and can modify your interface accordingly.

Comment: This sort of works for me. (See my updates for more info.)  I think I need to check for the `presentingViewController` on the place picker controller's internal navigation controller.